# Compute Bayesian Probability

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, distributions, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

I have following problem at hand.

Your recently bought a house and are thinking about buying a flood insurance for the year 2014. Indeed, your house is unfortunately located in a “high-risk” area where it is estimated that 80% house floods occur.

It is also known, that 0.05% of all houses are flooded every year and that 4% of all houses are in high-risk areas.

You estimate that a flood would cause exactly 100000 euros damage to your house (less than half of the market value).

The best insurance deal you could find is full flood coverage for a price of 1100 euros per year.

$1.\ State\ the\ Bayes\ rule\ and\ compute\ the\ probability\ that\  $
$your\ house\ will\ be\ flooded\ in\ the\ year\ 2014 $

I am trying to define Prior, Likelihood and Evidence probabilities but not sure is it correct or not and also not getting correct values.

$$P(F) = Flood\ Happening\ = 0.05\% $$
$$P(F|R)= Flood\ Happening\ given\ high\ risk\ area = 80\% * 0.05 = 0.04\% $$
$$P(R) = (not\ sure\ is\ it\ 4\%\ or\ this\ assumption\ is\ wrong)$$
$$Not\ sure\ do\ i\ need\ to\ calculate\ P(F|R)\ or\ P(R|F)$$
$$P(R|F)=(0.04\%*4\%)/(0.05\%)=3.2\%$$

Comment: I don't think you have interpreted the 80% correctly.

Comment: I updated my question and after solving with that assumption I am getting 3.2%. but not sure is it correct or not.